# Issue when creating windows service from command prompt

Tags: cmd, windows-services

I m trying to create windows service using cmd prompt and running as admin, I m using below command. Here I m using remote machine IP to deploy the service on remote machine.I'm able to login the credentials in remote machine using below username and password.Let me know what might be the wrong I'm doing here.

command using :-

```
sc \\101.010.99.323 create test_windows_service binpath= C:\Users\admin\desktop\TestWindowService\TestWindowService\bin\Debug\TestWindowService.exe start= auto obj= sample password= password
```

getting below error :- The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.

Thanks

Comment: It's an invalid IP address. Each byte can be a maximum value of 255. Your last one says 323.

Comment: @Noodles ip address is sample one just for example i gave.

Comment: This is the message `The account name is invalid or does not exist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified.`. Sample data won't cut it.

Comment: @Noodles using those credentials i m able to login into remote system. so those credentials are valid. what else might be the issue here